# Designing a database for user-customized groupings

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database-design

A user can search for colours and add them to their palette..

So if they write blue, blue will show up and they can add it.

so on with red, yellow.......

But I want, that if they choose "dark colors", then grey black and brown should be added.

Today I´m doing like this

```
if($color==darkcolor) 

insert black and grey and brown...
```

Is there any easier way to achieve this. I have hundreds of attributes I want to add and sitting and writing php if, else strings is to much time consuming...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a specific php/mysql problem here.

Your best bet would be to to add attributes to your colour database

e.g.

```
Name      Attribute
Green     Natural, Light
Brown     Natural, Dark
```

The you can simply `SELECT Name FROM Colours WHERE Attribute LIKE <Query String>`

If there are a limited number of attribute categories then you could specialise the table further by adding column names like "Lightness", "Theme" etc.

Comment: okay. it´s more complex then that. I have gotten a xml file with 2100 school courses.. That users can add to a schedule. The problem is that  3 courses on one semester maybe called course A, B, C.. But for the students in reality it´s called Course X that runs for one semester, and course X contains of those a,b,c but noone ever remembers their names.

My dream would be to have a simple back-admin form to say.

Make coursenname X contain a,b,c
Make coursename Z contain d,e,f

Comment: the color problem was just to illustrate the problem in a easy way,  sorry for my bad terminology

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up a database with a few tables.

```
colours
   id
   name

attributes
   id
   name

colour_attributes
   colour_id
   attribute_id
```

That way, you can keep track of an unlimited amount of colours and attributes, and tie attributes to colours via the association table `colour_attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a category table, so that you can keep track of them. Then, add a color_category table so you can have a many-to-many. Like so:

```
CategoryID    Category
----------------------
         1    primary
         2    dark

ColorID    CategoryID
---------------------
     1              1
     1              2
     2              2

ColorID    Color
-----------------
      1    red  
      2    brown
```

Next, have a UserPalette table that looks like this:

```
UserID    ColorID
-----------------
     1          3
     1          4
```

So, when a user selects `dark`, you would run this query:

```
insert into userpalette
select
    $userId as userid,
    c.colorid
from
    category cat
    inner join color_category cc on
        cat.categoryid = cc.categoryid
    inner join colors c on
        cat.colorid = c.colorid
where
    cat.category = '$category'
```

To grab a user's colors, you'd do this:

```
select
    c.color
from
    userpalette up
    inner join colors c on
        up.colorid = c.colorid
where
    up.userid = $userid
```

If you just have a username:

```
select
    *
from
    users u
    inner join userpalette up on
        u.userid = up.userid
    inner join colors c on
        up.colorid = c.colorid
where
    u.username = '$username'
```

Obviously, make sure you pipe everything through `mysql_real_escape_string()` before you put it into a SQL query. Otherwise, you're leaving yourself open for SQL injection attacks.